# Configuring Logback: report time from application start instead of current date/time

Tags: datetime, logback

During troubleshooting in development environment I would like to have time from application start instead of current date/time in logs.

Like in `dmesg` output.

What configuration and formatter I should use?

**UPDATE** There is an example from official site: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#writingYourOwnLayout where custom layout is implemented:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.core.LayoutBase;

public class MySampleLayout extends LayoutBase<ILoggingEvent> {

  public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
    StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer(128);
    sbuf.append(event.getTimeStamp() - event.getLoggingContextVO.getBirthTime());
    sbuf.append(" ");
    sbuf.append(event.getLevel());
    return sbuf.toString();
  }
}
```

For me it's over complicated. Such simple thing shouldn't require compilation but rather configuration... Why I need to repackage `jar` or extend `CLASSPATH` to include custom written writer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that official docs has notes on this:

```
r / relative    Outputs the number of milliseconds elapsed since the start
                of the application until the creation of the logging event.
```

But you can't format it as `date`:

```
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%r %5p [%15.15t] %logger%n%m%wEx%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
```